# How can i add a menuStrip menus for each item in a listBox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

What i want to do is that when i select an item in the listBox and then make right click on the item with the mouse it will show me a menu like Edit,Copy,Cut,Rename then if i click on for example Copy it will do something and if on Edit something else.

What i did in the form1 top is:

```
ContextMenuStrip menuStrip;
```

In the constructor:

```
menuStrip = new ContextMenuStrip();
menuStrip.ItemClicked += menuStrip_ItemClicked;
menuStrip.Items.Add("Cut");
menuStrip.Items.Add("Copy");
menuStrip.Items.Add("Paste");
```

Then in the menuStrip_ItemClicked event:

```
ListBox item;
        void menuStrip_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection selectedItems =
           lstDisplayHardware.SelectedItems;
            if (e.ClickedItem.Text == "Copy")
            {
                String text = "";
                foreach (ListViewItem item in selectedItems)
                {
                    text += item.SubItems[1].Text + Environment.NewLine;
                }
                Clipboard.SetText(text);
            }
        }
```

And the event of the click:

```
private void lstDisplayHardware_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                item = lstDisplayHardware.GetItemAt(e.X, e.Y);
                menuStrip.Show(lstDisplayHardware, e.Location);
            }
        }
```

lstDisplayHardware is my listView in my other project and in this one it should be listBox1.

The problem is that i took this example from my other project there i used it on a listView. But now i want to make it on a listBox.

Maybe i should use a listView also here ? Not sure when to use listView or listBox. In this project i'm using listBox to show list of my youtube videos so it's just a list string.

Comment: In Listbox you work with the Items collection that is an ObjectCollection. The exact nature of the single or multiple item selected depends on how do you fill the listbox. Of course Listbox has no concept of SubItems. How do you fill the Listbox? Do you have multiselection enabled on the Listbox?

Comment: I fill the listBox with the property Add in a loop adding strings. And how can i set it to multiselection, didn't find a property ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you only want a single value from the ListBox...

```
void menuStrip_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
{
    if(item != null && item.SelectedIndex > -1)
    {
        Clipboard.SetText(item.Items[item.SelectedIndex].ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to bind the context menu to the ListBox!?
Try this after adding your items to the context menu:

```
listBox1.ContextMenuStrip = menuStrip;
```